# Multiple Table SQL Statement

Tags: sql, database, join

I'm struggling with how to structure an SQL statement involving multiple tables and was wondering if anyone could help point me in the right direction.

I assume multiple JOINS will be needed, but I'm not entirely sure of how exactly they work.

Basically the system I need to create will allow teaching staff to view an HTML table of the assignment submissions with relevant details. Below is the ER diagram representing the database.

[image: ER Diagram]

Each row in the HTML table will relate to a particular assignment submission, and will include the following information - Forename of the student, Surname of the student, Module the assignment relates to, Assignment Name, a link to the feedback PDF document, the time the feedback was collected and the number of times the feedback was commented on.

So basically I need an SQL statement that would return the information mentioned above.

I probably haven't explained this too well, but hopefully the diagram can help fill in the parts I have missed.

Comment: Please have a look at how we edited your question to make it more readable.

Comment: I assume ViewCount is the number of times feedback was commented on and LastViewed is the time the feedback was collected. Right?

Comment: Also very unlikely in your case, the answer *could* be DBMS specific. So you might want to add a tag that corresponds to the DBMS you use (Oracle, Postgres, ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Forename,
    Surname,
    ModuleName,
    sa.StudentID as StudentID,
    sa.AssignmentID as AssignmentID,
    FeedbackURL,
    FirstViewed, 
    LastViewed,
    ViewCount,
    a.Name AS AssignmentName,
FROM assignment AS a
INNER JOIN student_assignment AS sa ON a.AssignmentID=sa.AssignmentID
INNER JOIN student AS s ON sa.StudentID=s.StudentID
INNER JOIN course AS c ON s.CourseID=c.CourseID
INNER JOIN course_module AS cm ON c.CourseID=cm.CourseID
INNER JOIN module AS m ON cm.CRN=m.CRN
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. unfortunately when I tried running the code through PHPMyAdmin it brought up the error #1052 - Column 'Name' in field list is ambiguous.

Sorry i'm a beginner when it comes to JOINS.

Comment: @user3034211 no problem at all ! Give me a few seconds.

Comment: @user3034211 Give it a shot now and please let me know for the result.

Comment: @user3034211 Hey, did you try it?

Comment: Hey again, yeah the new statement worked without errors. However I've realised that I didn't explain what I was looking very well at all.

The statement should basically select all entries in the student_assignment table and return the FeedbackURL and FirstViewed. 

It will then have to use the StudentID associated with the entry to pull Forename and Surname from student table. It will also have to pull in the Name from assignment and ModuleName from module.

I hope that makes a bit more sense. Let me know if you want anything else explained.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user3034211 Ok, I will change the query. Try it and let me know for the results.

Comment: @user3034211 Now I think it is ok. If you don't like the ordering of the results, simple change them. For instance, If you want Surname first and Forename second, write SELECT Surname, Forename,....

Comment: That statement appears to returning entries for each of the modules in the database, not just the entries in the student_assignment table.

There are only two entries in the student_assignment table but it is returning over 30 entries which makes me believe it is something to do with all the modules in the database.

Comment: @user3034211 Since we use INNER JOIN, that's impossible. If there are no associated rows across to the tables we join, we don't get any data. So that seems to me weird. Also, since you you didn't mention a problem like that before, I can't understand how that appeared.